# Calling unions of function types with different arguments

Tags: typescript

I understand why for type-safety calling a union of function types requires the intersection of the parameters.

But, as a matter of practicality, how can I make it work in the example below where I need a function that takes as params `(fn, params)` and calls internally `fn(params)`?

```
type FuncUnion = ((n: number) => string) | ((s: string) => string);

const fnWrapper = <TFn extends FuncUnion, TParams extends Parameters<TFn>[0]>(f: TFn, params: TParams) => {

    f(params);
};
```

[on the typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMYFUEEsD2CoF4oAUBCAXFAnALYBGEATgJR4B8UAzsHeggOZMA+hAmzIcuvJrlZjufANwBYAFDKk2DlABmOfAB4AKjBwQAHsAgIAJm1iJUGbABoo+gAoBDOu8o3T5qzYeXpQQ5nRsBkbMANoADAC6zASaZIYIzmCe3iIuQdmSrADeyspQZVoEmcFsDIpKAL5yQA)

In the example above, the params of f are `never` since it gets made into `number & string` which no types satisfy. This makes it impossible to call `f` with any parameters, although I also know when calling this that my `params` are suitable for `f` once I've narrowed `FuncUnion` down to a single function like this:

`fnWrapper( (a: number) => 'r', 2 ) );`

Is there any way that this can work?

Answer (score 0):

You can make `fn` generic, and instead of basing the type of `param` on the function type, base the function type on the type of `param` (I've used the singular since it's just one param):

```typescript
const fn = <ParamType extends string | number, FuncType extends (arg: ParamType) => string>(
    f: FuncType, 
    param: ParamType
) => {
    f(param);
};
```

Then you get the correct inference from the type of function passed in:

```typescript
// Works, since `s` is inferred as string
fn((s) => s, "hi");

// Works, `n` is inferred as number and the function converts it to string
fn((n) => String(n), 42);

// Error as desired, since `n` is inferred as number
fn((n) => n, 42);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZmGBeGAeACgQwE6YLYAqAngA4CmMZAHlGWACYQzTYCWYA5jAD4xgCueAEZlsAGhgAxfmGDFylGnUYwAFDg4AuGFlyFSZAJTIAfMyhtOJ1QFgAUDEfxt02fLIT7TmCRz5tuvju9sZIZgDeXk5wqr56hgDc9gC+SXb2APQZMADqINgA1hASEOzAFAAGEBUwrEzscKLYZPQwmEws7Bz2CKqqEKFmxTAARAAWrCOJ9pnZeYXDFWA1dbVgjdjNre18giLYbQwwUGMUcDLAUKzgMKBgAG6iUPWwUCDmlt12vapggzAAZQsXV+hgkABYAEzTdJ2LIwACim3ybSY9DIpS2JTKlWWtXq6yaLVRu2Eoh6YD6f1MfAh0LSQA)

---

If you want to support functions with multiple parameters, you can do that using rest and spread:

```typescript
const fn = <ParamsType extends any[], FuncType extends (...args: ParamsType) => string>(
    f: FuncType, 
    ...params: ParamsType
) => {
    f(...params);
};
```

Now these work as well as the earlier examples:

```
// Works with multiple arguments, even with diverse types
fn((s1, s2) => s1 + s2, "one", "two");
fn((n, s) => s.substring(n), 5, "b");
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=38&pln=17&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZmGBeGAeACgQwE6YLYQAqAngA4CmM5AHlOWACYQyZjEDaAugDQwBiAVzDASFKrXpMYACgB08nAHMIALhhZcBUeQCUyAHwxo2AJZhF+6QFgAUDHvw1g4dt62HMebNI58q9b5aZOS2ekiGAN7uDnBy8j6aEDoA3LYAvqk2tgD02TAA6iDYANYQvBBmwJQABhDVMCbMZnDk2NjkDCzMxmaKtgjS0kkGRrwARAAWJmMptjl5hSVlMNVg9Y0NYC1tHV0wYAJ4AEatLIwwUBOUcELAUCbgMKBgAG6tUE2wUCBGUKbm-TAgzAYUMAGU-r1pCDeAAWABMsyyNlyMAAom0insGOQKu0GOVKjU1g0mltWvi9gdjq1AcDQfs4YjMvMCkVSjAAO4mS4wPACAA291IAsoSkO9A+vHIb0Q3N5DBMb2wEEoUGCEDpQwAjOVESMINqYABqIzw8bgchjcZQTkgGaZAbQ8oMiCyCACI49czQnS8ACs4yODqAA)

In that I haven't limited the parameter types, but if you wanted to limit the types to `number | string`, you could use `ParamsType extends (string | number)[]` instead of `ParamsType extends any[]`. Or if you wanted to allow only strings or only numbers, it would be `ParamsType extends string[] | number[]`. Or whatever else you want. :-)